# Unity Script Error (Error CS0118)

Tags: c#

Please help me fix the error.
The message is:
"Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(6,21): error CS0118: `GameManager.character' is a`field' but a `type' was expected"
The error is on (6, 21). Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
public List<character> character = new List<character>(); <-- (ERROR CS0118)

bool ShowCharWheel;
public int SelectedCharacter;
public int xcount;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)){
    {
            ShowCharWheel = true;
    }

    {
            ShowCharWheel = false;
    }


    //Camera.main.GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = characters[SelectedCharacter].

    if (ShowCharWheel)
    {
                    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 64, Screen.height - 192,64,192));
            {
                if(GUILayout.Button(c.icon,GUILayout.Width(64),GUILayout.Height(64)))
                foreach (character c in Characters)
                {
                    SelectedCharacter = character.IndexOf(c);
                }
            }
        }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Character
{   
public string name;
public Texture2D icon;
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject instance;
public Transform HomeSpawn;
}
```

Needed more details other than code, so ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps just need to capitalize? C# is case sensitive.

```
public List<Character> characterList = new List<Character>();
```

I also renamed your variable for clarity.

Comment: I tried it and it gave me another error. Can you fix that to?
"Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(34,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `character' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: @LightSpeedCo. You're probably running into that here: `foreach (character c in Characters)`. Same problem. You need to capitalize the c in `character` so it reads `foreach (Character c in characterList)`. I also changed the variable name to mine.